# How to connect loop data to pdfgeneratorapi with wix corvid?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, pdf-generation, velo

I'm generating PDF by using https://pdfgeneratorapi.com/.

Now I can show data one by one using this code.Can any one give me suggestion how can show all data with loop or any other way?
This below photos showing my template from pdfgenerator .

[image]

This is the code I'm using to generate PDF

```
    let communicationWay1=[
    {0:"dim"},
    {1:"kal"}
    ];
    let cstomerExpence1=[
    {0:"dim"}, 
    {1:"kal"}
    ];
   let title="test";
   let names="test";
   let phone="test";
   let email="test";
let maritalStatus="test";
let city="test";
let other="test";

 const result = await wixData.query(collection)
 .eq('main_user_email', $w('#mainE').text)
         .find()
    .then( (results) => {
 if (results.totalCount>0) {
                    count=1;
 // title=results.items[1].title;
                        names=results.items[0].names;
                        email=results.items[0].emial;
                        phone=results.items[0].phone;
                        maritalStatus=results.items[0].maritalStatus;
                        city=results.items[0].city;
                        other=results.items[0].cousterExpenses_other;                       
                        title=results.items[0].title;
 
                        communicationWay=results.items[0].communicationWay;
                        cstomerExpence=results.items[0].cstomerExpence;

                }
 if (results.totalCount>1) {              
                        names1=results.items[1].names;
                        email1=results.items[1].emial;
                        phone1=results.items[1].phone;
                        maritalStatus1=results.items[1].maritalStatus;
                        city1=results.items[1].city;
                        other1=results.items[1].cousterExpenses_other;                      
                        title1=results.items[1].title;
                        communicationWay1=results.items[1].communicationWay;
                        cstomerExpence1=results.items[1].cstomerExpence;
                }
 
    } )
    .catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    } );
 // Add your code for this event here:  
 const pdfUrl = await getPdfUrl
 ({title,names,email,phone,city,maritalStatus,other,communicationWay,cstomerExpence,title1,
  names1,email1,phone1,city1,maritalStatus1,other1,communicationWay1,cstomerExpence1   
    });
if (count===0) {    $w("#text21").show();}
else{        $w("#downloadButton").link=wixLocation.to(pdfUrl);}
```

BELOW CODE IS BACKEND CODE/JSW CODE.
Also I want to open pdf in new tab. I know "_blank" method can be used to open a new tab.But I'm not sure how to add it with the url

```
 import PDFGeneratorAPI from 'pdf-generator-api'

const apiKey = 'MYKEY';
const apiSecret = 'MYAPISECRET';

const baseUrl = 'https://us1.pdfgeneratorapi.com/api/v3/';
const workspace = "HELLO@gmail.com";
const templateID = "MYTEMPLATEID";

let Client = new PDFGeneratorAPI(apiKey, apiSecret)
Client.setBaseUrl(baseUrl)
Client.setWorkspace(workspace)

export async function getPdfUrl(data) {
 const {response} = await Client.output(templateID, data, undefined, undefined, {output: 'url'})
 return response
}
```

Comment: let's start with your template first: I think you need to wrap the lines in a "container" item from the template editor. Then you can repeat each line for every item in a collection in the data. Check the "Invoice" template example from their site for how they are doing line items. This will let you pass data to the API as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a while loop with a boolean condition.

You can create a variable, for example `allShowed`, and set its value to `False`. After that, create another variable, for example `numberOfDataToShow`, and set it as the number of elements you want to display. Then create a counter, `countShowed`, initialized with `0` as its value.

Now create a while loop: while `allShowed` value is `False`, you loop (and add data).
Everytime a piece of your data is showed, you increment the value of `countShowed` (and set it to go on adding/showing data). When `countShowed` will have the exact same value of `numberOfDataToShow`, set `allShowed` to `True`. The loop will interrupt and all your data will be showed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [Container](https://support.pdfgeneratorapi.com/en/article/container-component-5fi9zb/) or [Table](https://support.pdfgeneratorapi.com/en/article/table-component-1fuaafc/) component in PDF Generator API to iterate over a list of items. As @JustCallMeA said you need to send an array of items. PDF Generator API now has an official Wix Velo (previously Corvid) tutorial with a demo page: https://support.pdfgeneratorapi.com/en/article/how-to-integrate-with-wix-velo-13s8135